# Unity:How to realize a modal message box?

Tags: unity, gui

I'm developing a simple "modal" MessageBox.

This is the code inside Message Box panel:

```
public void Show(string _title , string _message, bool _showYesButton, bool _showNoButton, bool _showCancelButton) {
    this.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    Title.text = _title;
    Message.text = _message;
    btnYes.SetActive (_showYesButton);
    btnNo.SetActive (_showNoButton);
    btnCancel.SetActive (_showCancelButton);


}
```

And here how I call it outside:

```
MyMessageBoxScript _script = MyMsgBoxGameObject.GetComponent<MyMessageBoxScript >();
_script.Show("Hey..","Are you sure you want to overwrite this save ?",true,true,false);
```

Ok.. the problem is that I can't do a "modal" window, like in .NET version, returning what user pressed.

Something like:

```
buttonPressed = _script.Show("Hey.:", "Are you sure...");
```

So, searching with Google someone use this Way :

```
_script.Show(CallBackFunction; "Hey..","Are you sure you want to overwrite this save ?",true,true,false);
```

and

```
void CallBackFunction () {
...
}
```

**But I can't understand how it works: How to pass CallBackFunction as parameter and how to execute (after clicking: yes,no or cancel) ?**

Thanks

Comment: Here's a tutorial from Unity on [making a generic modal window](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window)... might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter to `public void Show` of type [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx). Action is a [delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)-type representing a method with no arguments and a return type of `void`.

You can then add that delegate to the [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event handler of the OK button.

```
public void Show(Action callback, string _title , string _message, bool _showYesButton, bool _showNoButton, bool _showCancelButton) {
    this.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    Title.text = _title;
    Message.text = _message;
    btnYes.SetActive (_showYesButton);
    btnYes.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();  // remove previous callback
    btnYes.onClick.AddListener(callback);  // add the new one
    btnNo.SetActive (_showNoButton);
    btnCancel.SetActive (_showCancelButton);
}
```